# Removing a hvac branch duct

Tags: hvac

I'm looking to finish my basement, and wanted to remove all forced air ducts at the ceiling and do floor heating for the basement.

Since I'm a noob in hvac, couple questions:

Can I just cut off these hvac duct branches at the trunk? And how and what do I patch it with?

[image]

Comment: Not an expert in HVAC but I think you'll need to provide more info. One or two is probably not an issue, more than that may be. How many do you plan to cut off and how many total in the house. What about A/C, how do you plan to cool the basement? Maybe your basement is cool in the summer but you still want some air circulation.

Comment: Couple of suggestions. 1) Make sure when you remove vents that you retain sufficient air flow through your air handler.  Without it you get fast cycling and possibly frozen A/C.   2) Instead of removing them, just keep them closed.  You never know if you'll need extra heat/cooling, perhaps if the floor heat fails.  It's there already.

Comment: there's 3 in total that I want to remove. A/C isn't required for basement since it's not hot in the summer. Ventilation isn't an issue since it's a walkout basement with adequate windows.

Comment: Would capping it off at the end be a safer bet instead of terminating at the trunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They sell vent caps that you can push fit into the truck and then just metal tape or buy some of the duct sealing mastic.

Something like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/Vent-Systems-Galvanized-Fitting-Reusable/dp/B09HL2R1ZX/ref=sr_1_16?crid=M75BOJUGRGC0&keywords=sheet+metal+vent+cap&qid=1641865475&sprefix=sheet+metal+vent+cap%2Caps%2C115&sr=8-16](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09HL2R1ZX)

Easiest thing is to measure and then go into your hvac wholesaler and ask them.  I can't see a problem with sealing them at the truck given you can close the vents using the register.